# Delete images from v2 private registry (leaves behined empty repository with tags of the images it contained)

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I tried deleting images from a private registry
post which the blobs and the manifest of the pushed image gets deleted .

but it leaves behind an empty repository with the tag of the images which it contained .

### Steps Followed:

`docker push hostname.xxx.yyy.com:1111/hello-world-abc`  push the image
The push refers to a repository [`hostname.xxx.yyy.com:1111/hello-world-abc`]

```
(len: 1)
aef768067415: Pushed
82152269d8b3: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:c7d713292dd6dc833ef6364cc6c821ce9523883bc97cc24bedbc572343644b68 size: 1937  get the digest value of the pushed image

[root@slc01olq docker]# curl -i -X GET hostname.xxx.yyy.com:1111/v2/hello-world-abc/manifests/latest  get the blobs associated with the image
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{
"schemaVersion": 1,
"name": "hello-world-abc",
"tag": "latest",
"architecture": "amd64",
"fsLayers": [
{
"blobSum": "sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4"
},
{
"blobSum": "sha256:4276590986f6a900029d4afb65b0969777f5ff9f70a00f896ec3b7372072381c"
```

• Delete the manifest and the Blobs::

```
curl -i -X DELETE hostname.xxx.yyy.com:1111/v2/hello-world-abc/manifests/sha256:c7d713292dd6dc833ef6364cc6c821ce9523883bc97cc24bedbc572343644b68
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted

curl -i -X DELETE hostname.xxx.yyy.com:1111/v2/hello-world-abc/blobs/sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted

curl -i -X DELETE hostname.xxx.yyy.com:1111/v2/hello-world-abc/blobs/sha256:4276590986f6a900029d4afb65b0969777f5ff9f70a00f896ec3b7372072381c
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
```

• Try to pull ::

```
docker pull hostname.xxx.yyy.com:1111/hello-world-abc

Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository hostname.xxx.yyy.com:1111/hello-world-abc
Error: image hello-world-abc:latest not found
```

• Search the image

```
docker search hostname.xxx.yyy.com:1111/hello-world-abc
NAME DESCRIPTION STARS OFFICIAL AUTOMATED
hostname.xxx.yyy.com:1111/hello-world-abc:latest 0

curl -i -X GET hostname.xxx.yyy.com:1111/v2/hello-world-abc/tags/list
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{"name":"hello-world-abc","tags":[“latest"]}
```

Problem statement  The image is getting deleted , but an empty repository remains and I want to delete this as the above search returns an o/p :: `{"name":"hello-world-abc","tags":["latest"]}`  but actually the latest tag has been deleted